# Matching two matrices depending on diagonal elements of two matrices in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Below are the two adjacency matrices.I have to find which row of matrix1 is correspond to which row in matrix2 depending on diagonal values.In below example

`1st row=1st row(diagonal value=4)`

`2nd row=5th row(diagonal value=5)`

`3rd row=4th row(diagonal value=1)`

`4th row=2nd row(diagonal value=3)`

`5th row=3rd row(diagonal value=2)`

```
 4     4     1     3     2
 4     5     1     3     2
 1     1     1     1     1
 3     3     1     3     2
 2     2     1     2     2

 4     3     2     1     4
 3     3     2     1     3
 2     2     2     1     2
 1     1     1     1     1
 4     3     2     1     5
```

How it can be done in matlab?

Comment: What if there is no match found in the second matrix? Would it be possible?

Comment: Apologies for being thick but could you explain how `3rd row=4th row(diagonal value=1)`? I expect it to be `3rd row=1st row(diagonal value=1)` as the diagonal value is 1. Does the diagional value not represent the row number in matrix 2?

Comment: @kkuilla 3rd row diag element in matrix1 is `1` that matches with the row 4th diag element of matrix 2 that is `1` too. I think this is the case.

Comment: Ah, I see. We are only working on the diagonals and then extract the row numbers where the value of the diagonals are equal to each other. That makes sense. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second output of [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[~, result] = ismember(diag(matrix1), diag(matrix2))
```

In your example, this returns

```
result =
     1
     5
     4
     2
     3
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `mat1` and `mat2` to be the first and second matrices respectively and that you are looking to find the first match of diagonal values, try this -

```
[~,ind] = max(bsxfun(@eq,diag(mat2),diag(mat1)'))
```

or

```
[~,ind] = max(bsxfun(@eq,diag(mat1),diag(mat2)'),[],2)
```

If you are certain that there are always unique matches, you can use `find` too -

```
[ind,~] = find(bsxfun(@eq,diag(mat2),diag(mat1)'))
```